# LABEL disapper when textfield is added

Tags: java, user-interface, label, textfield

i am new to java..i wrote the following code

```
package javaapplication17;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class NewClass  extends JFrame{
    public NewClass(){
        this("");
    }

    public NewClass(){
        super("my application");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        JLabel label=new JLabel("hello world");

       // this.add(label);
       // JTextField text;
       // text = new JTextField(15);

        //this.add(text);          

        this.setVisible(true);
    }       
}
```

when I remove the comments in the above code the label showing hello world disappear..why?

Comment: You need to learn about [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)!

Comment: You need to use a Layout Manager, e.g. BoxLayout, otherwise you just replace the JLabel with the JTextField.